# Is there any means to log the system logs in a separate file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, cocoalumberjack

I am using CocoaLumberjack to log whatever things that I require for debugging.

In addition to that I also require some additional console messages to be printed out, i.e. certain warnings that were raised in the system console etc.

Is there any means I can get the logs from the system console?

Comment: CocoaLumberjack can log to a file.  Why don't you do that as well?

Comment: ya it can log but i need to get the console logs

Comment: You mean the logs from something outside your application?

Answer (score 0):

```
Xcode->organizer->devices->your device->console
```